# How to convert missing values to the mean of the other values in R?

Tags: r, missing-data

I need to convert the missing values of a column in a dataframe with the rest of values of this column, grouped by Districts and Month. 
This is a sample of my df1:

```
       Date   Day Month Year  Districts Numberofpeople
1   2017-01-01  01  01  2017    Berri1  38
2   2017-01-02  02  01  2017    Berri1  109
3   2017-01-03  03  01  2017    Berri1  141
4   2017-01-04  04  01  2017    Berri1  233
5   2017-01-05  05  01  2017    Berri1  265
6   2017-01-06  06  01  2017    Berri1  306
7   2017-01-07  07  01  2017    Berri1  96
8   2017-01-08  08  01  2017    Berri1  113
9   2017-01-09  09  01  2017    Berri1  362
10  2017-01-10  10  01  2017    Berri1  451
11  2017-01-11  11  01  2017    Berri1  458
12  2017-01-12  12  01  2017    Berri1  440
13  2017-01-13  13  01  2017    Berri1  398
14  2017-01-14  14  01  2017    Berri1  125
15  2017-01-15  15  01  2017    Berri1  120
16  2017-01-16  16  01  2017    Berri1  507
17  2017-01-17  17  01  2017    Berri1  576
18  2017-01-18  18  01  2017    Berri1  459
19  2017-01-19  19  01  2017    Berri1  495
20  2017-01-20  20  01  2017    Berri1  518
21  2017-01-21  21  01  2017    Berri1  265
22  2017-01-22  22  01  2017    Berri1  194
23  2017-01-23  23  01  2017    Berri1  557
24  2017-01-24  24  01  2017    Berri1  185
25  2017-01-25  25  01  2017    Berri1  434
26  2017-01-26  26  01  2017    Berri1  518
27  2017-01-27  27  01  2017    Berri1  441
28  2017-01-28  28  01  2017    Berri1  173
29  2017-01-29  29  01  2017    Berri1  173
30  2017-01-30  30  01  2017    Berri1  421
609 2017-09-01  01  09  2017    Boyer   3702
610 2017-09-02  02  09  2017    Boyer   3561
611 2017-09-03  03  09  2017    Boyer   465
612 2017-09-04  04  09  2017    Boyer   2130
613 2017-09-05  05  09  2017    Boyer   3420
614 2017-09-06  06  09  2017    Boyer   3844
615 2017-09-07  07  09  2017    Boyer   2349
616 2017-09-08  08  09  2017    Boyer   3398
617 2017-09-09  09  09  2017    Boyer   3004
618 2017-09-10  10  09  2017    Boyer   3263
619 2017-09-11  11  09  2017    Boyer   4333
620 2017-09-12  12  09  2017    Boyer   4577
621 2017-09-13  13  09  2017    Boyer   4682
622 2017-09-14  14  09  2017    Boyer   4737
623 2017-09-15  15  09  2017    Boyer   4441
624 2017-09-16  16  09  2017    Boyer   4015
625 2017-09-17  17  09  2017    Boyer   3810
626 2017-09-18  18  09  2017    Boyer   4208
627 2017-09-19  19  09  2017    Boyer   4628
628 2017-09-20  20  09  2017    Boyer   4389
629 2017-09-21  21  09  2017    Boyer   4543
630 2017-09-22  22  09  2017    Boyer   4508
631 2017-09-23  23  09  2017    Boyer   3878
632 2017-09-24  24  09  2017    Boyer   3338
633 2017-09-25  25  09  2017    Boyer   3961
634 2017-09-26  26  09  2017    Boyer   4235
635 2017-09-27  27  09  2017    Boyer   3336
636 2017-09-28  28  09  2017    Boyer   3897
637 2017-09-29  29  09  2017    Boyer   3448
638 2017-09-30  30  09  2017    Boyer   2692
639 2017-10-01  01  10  2017    Boyer   2667
640 2017-10-02  02  10  2017    Boyer   3617
641 2017-10-03  03  10  2017    Boyer   4063
642 2017-10-04  04  10  2017    Boyer   2750
643 2017-10-05  05  10  2017    Boyer   3491
644 2017-10-06  06  10  2017    Boyer   3723
645 2017-10-07  07  10  2017    Boyer   1508
646 2017-10-08  08  10  2017    Boyer   1718
647 2017-10-09  09  10  2017    Boyer   589
648 2017-10-10  10  10  2017    Boyer   3482
649 2017-10-11  11  10  2017    Boyer   3140
650 2017-10-12  12  10  2017    Boyer   3700
651 2017-10-13  13  10  2017    Boyer   3249
652 2017-10-14  14  10  2017    Boyer   1935
653 2017-10-15  15  10  2017    Boyer   1047
654 2017-10-16  16  10  2017    Boyer   2535
655 2017-10-17  17  10  2017    Boyer   2683
656 2017-10-18  18  10  2017    Boyer   3293
657 2017-10-19  19  10  2017    Boyer   3268
658 2017-10-20  20  10  2017    Boyer   3136
659 2017-10-21  21  10  2017    Boyer   3023
660 2017-10-22  22  10  2017    Boyer   2387
661 2017-10-23  23  10  2017    Boyer   3232
662 2017-10-24  24  10  2017    Boyer   1246
663 2017-10-25  25  10  2017    Boyer   2899
664 2017-10-26  26  10  2017    Boyer   1726
665 2017-10-27  27  10  2017    Boyer   2468
666 2017-10-28  28  10  2017    Boyer   2450
667 2017-10-29  29  10  2017    Boyer   656
668 2017-10-30  30  10  2017    Boyer   1175
669 2017-10-31  31  10  2017    Boyer   1923
670 2017-11-01  01  11  2017    Boyer   1906
671 2017-11-02  02  11  2017    Boyer   889
672 2017-11-03  03  11  2017    Boyer   1632
673 2017-11-04  04  11  2017    Boyer   1486
674 2017-11-05  05  11  2017    Boyer   508
675 2017-11-06  06  11  2017    Boyer   1438
676 2017-11-07  07  11  2017    Boyer   1844
677 2017-11-08  08  11  2017    Boyer   1776
678 2017-11-09  09  11  2017    Boyer   1705
679 2017-11-10  10  11  2017    Boyer   855
680 2017-11-11  11  11  2017    Boyer   654
681 2017-11-12  12  11  2017    Boyer   670
682 2017-11-13  13  11  2017    Boyer   1182
683 2017-11-14  14  11  2017    Boyer   1430
684 2017-11-15  15  11  2017    Boyer   1530
685 2017-11-16  16  11  2017    Boyer   854
686 2017-11-17  17  11  2017    Boyer   992
687 2017-11-18  18  11  2017    Boyer   556
688 2017-11-19  19  11  2017    Boyer   196
689 2017-11-20  20  11  2017    Boyer   401
690 2017-11-21  21  11  2017    Boyer   919
```

The data types are the following:

```
 sapply(pob_tidy8, class)
          Date            Day          Month           Year      Districts Numberofpeople 
        "Date"    "character"    "character"    "character"    "character"      "numeric"
```

I tried this:

```
df1 <- df
df1%>%
  group_by(Districts, Month) %>%
  mutate(Numberofpeople = if_else(is.na(Numberofpeople), mean(Numberofpeople, na.rm = T), Numberofpeople))
```

But when I check if there are missing values using which I see I still have missing values.

```
any(is.na(pob_tidy8$Numberofpeople))
[1] TRUE
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because this question doesn't deal with explicitly spatial data, but rather with programing in R, it would have been more appropriate for the forum at http://stackoverflow.com. That said, I can certainly see where this problem would arise in a spatial context.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses data for two districts and two months. The means for each district/month combination are calculated and substituted for NAs.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

a_jan <- rnorm(5, mean = 10)
b_jan <- rnorm(5, mean = 20)
a_feb <- rnorm(5, mean = 30)
b_feb <- rnorm(5, mean = 40)

nas <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), size = 20, prob = c(30,70), replace = TRUE)
districts <- c("A", "B")
months <- month.name[1:2]
df <- tibble(District = factor(rep(districts, 10)),
             Month = factor(rep(months, each = 10))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Month), District) %>%
  mutate(Value = c(a_jan, b_jan, a_feb, b_feb))

df$Value <- ifelse(nas, NA, df$Value)
df

# # A tibble: 20 x 3
# District Month    Value
# <fct>    <fct>    <dbl>
#   1 A        January   NA  
# 2 A        January   10.2
# 3 A        January   NA  
# 4 A        January   11.6
# 5 A        January   10.3
# 6 B        January   NA  
# 7 B        January   20.5
# 8 B        January   20.7
# 9 B        January   NA  
# 10 B        January   19.7
# 11 A        February  31.5
# 12 A        February  NA  
# 13 A        February  29.4
# 14 A        February  27.8
# 15 A        February  31.1
# 16 B        February  40.0
# 17 B        February  40.0
# 18 B        February  40.9
# 19 B        February  40.8
# 20 B        February  40.6

# Note that when calculating the means, we have to tell R to remove NAs
# in the calculation, or the resulting mean will be NA leaving us
# right where we started. Also, if you want to use the grand mean rather
# than the group mean, then simply skip the `group_by`. Or if you want
# to use the mean across months for each district, just `group_by(District)`
# or use the mean across districts for each month with `group_by(Month)`

df <- df %>%
  group_by(District, Month) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(test = is.na(Value), yes = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE), no = Value))

df
# # A tibble: 20 x 3
# # Groups:   District, Month [4]
# District Month    Value
# <fct>    <fct>    <dbl>
#   1 A        January   10.7
# 2 A        January   10.2
# 3 A        January   10.7
# 4 A        January   11.6
# 5 A        January   10.3
# 6 B        January   20.3
# 7 B        January   20.5
# 8 B        January   20.7
# 9 B        January   20.3
# 10 B        January   19.7
# 11 A        February  31.5
# 12 A        February  30.0
# 13 A        February  29.4
# 14 A        February  27.8
# 15 A        February  31.1
# 16 B        February  40.0
# 17 B        February  40.0
# 18 B        February  40.9
# 19 B        February  40.8
# 20 B        February  40.6
```

Comment: thank you. After I tried this I still have NA values...

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your problem in your question. You are using different code and/or data than what I wrote for you and we have no way to guess what you might be doing.

Comment: I updated the question with a sample of my dataframe. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is correct the sample I showed you?